# DataGridview checkbox is checked when form loading

Tags: checkbox, datagridview, form-load

I open form,but the dataview ,the first cells ,can not checked.
my code is below,i wanna all the checkboxcell is checked default.this code inside form_load. who have good idea. i have tested many ways.

DataGridView1.Refresh();
 int count = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.RowCount.ToString());

```
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
            checkCell.Value = true;
            Boolean flag = Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.Value);
            if (flag == false)     
            {
                checkCell.Value = true;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmXv3.png)

Comment: The posted code appears to set all the check boxes to true. However, the posted code has some logic issues. I would recommend you trace the posted code and see what happens. If you simply want to set all the check boxes in the column to true, then simply set it, checking for its current value is unnecessary. If you trace the logic in the for loop you will see that `flag` will NEVER be false.

Comment: The code sets `checkCell` to the current rows check box column (0). Then the code sets `checkCell.Value` to “true” (checked). The code then creates a Boolean variable `flag` from (a questionable conversion) `Convert.ToBoolean(checkCell.Value)`. This will obviously always set `flag` to “True” since the previous line of code set `checkCell.Value` to “true”. Therefore, `flag` will never be false. Again, this check seems unnecessary if you simply want to set each check box in the column to “true” then the only line you need in the loop is: `DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;`